# Incorrect Search Results pushing to MenuItem - React

Tags: reactjs

I've created three different components that search for users based on different statuses, and pushes these results into a MenuItem dropdown. The search function (below) is where I set the state for the particular set of Users in the first component (all 3 components are essentially the same, but are searching for different User types).

```
private loadData() {
 const sr = new SearchRequest();
 sr.addFilter("ls_status", "Active");
 searchUsers(this.props.app.api, sr).then((r: SearchResults<User>) => {
  this.setState({
    loanSpecialists: r.results
  });
 });
}
```

I then map these results to the Menu Item dropdown.

```
   const opts = this.state.loanSpecialists.map(n => (
   <MenuItem key={n.id} value={n.email.replace("@credibilitycapital.com", "")}>
    {n.email.replace("@credibilitycapital.com", "")}
   </MenuItem>
 ));
```

And then call {opts} in the TextField where the menu dropdown is displayed.

```
<TextField
  select
  fullWidth
  variant="outlined"
  value={this.state.assignedLs}
  onChange={this.updateAssignment()}
  margin="normal"
 >
  <MenuItem value="Unassigned">Unassigned</MenuItem>
    {opts}
 </TextField>
```

BUT the dropdown only displays the correct Users ~50% of the time. The rest of the time, it displays the correct Users plus the Users that should only be appearing in the other two dropdowns. I think the issue is coming from the searchUsers function because when I look at the results in Developer Tools, res.numHits and res.results differ when they should be the same.

[image: screenshot of search results]

API route for searchUsers (db = gorm.DB):

```
au := lorpAuthenticated.Group("/users")
au.POST("/search", routes.SearchHandler(db, &user.User{}, &[]user.User{}))
```

SearchHandler func:

```
func SearchHandler(db *gorm.DB, model, results interface{}, filters ...func(c echo.Context, sr *search.SearchRequest)) func(c echo.Context) error {
return func(c echo.Context) error {
    var sr search.SearchRequest

    if err := c.Bind(&sr); err != nil {
        return handleErr(err, "Error binding SearchRequest")
    }

    // Apply filters
    for _, filter := range filters {
        filter(c, &sr)
    }

    if err := sr.ToGorm(db).Find(results).Error; err != nil {
        return handleErr(err, "Error executing search")
    }

    hits, err := sr.ExecuteCount(db, model)
    if err != nil {
        return handleErr(err, "Error executing count")
    }

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, struct {
        Results interface{} `json:"results"`
        NumHits int         `json:"numHits"`
    }{
        Results: results,
        NumHits: hits,
    })
 }
}
```

I've been trying to debug this for over a week and am losing my mind--any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This could very well be an issue with your API. It is really hard to tell what is happening in your code without looking at a data sample or knowing how your api is operating.

Comment: The numHits vs results seems to be an api response issue.
Also, why are you are only using one state value for all 3 user types.
Why not add additional states based on status so that there is no conflict

Comment: @varoons I am using 3 different states for the 3 different user types. I only included 1 in my above post for brevity's sake and the fact that the code is essentially the same for all 3 with different states.

Comment: @Annjawn I've edited my original post to include some API info. Let me know if you need any more info to help. Thanks